# How to handle POST message body in python http.server

Tags: python, http, post, server, io

I have a problem that my http server in python stalls when I try to read the message body of a POST request.

This is a minimal version of the "server":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
  
import http.server
from http import HTTPStatus
import socketserver
from datetime import datetime

HOST="127.0.0.1"
PORT=9001

class MyHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

  def do_POST(self):
    print( self.rfile.read().decode("utf-8") )
    self.send_response(HTTPStatus.OK,"ok")
    self.send_header( "Content-type", "text/plain" )
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write( "OK".encode("utf-8") )
    self.wfile.flush()


socketserver.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
with socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyHandler) as httpd:
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

This is the request:

```
curl http://localhost:9001/list -d "hello server"
```

After CTRL-C on curl the read continues, but then sending the reply fails for obvious reason.

Does anyone know what is wrong here? I suspect that the http.server is not working properly, or I am doing something blatantly wrong (which in turn means that the the CGIHTTPRequesthandler is badly broken, because of):

I discovered that problem while playing with CGIHTTPRequesthandler where a called cgi python program hang on `sys.stdin.read()` (which is basically a os.dup2'ed version of rfile.read() there). (The sys.stdin.read() works just fine in nginx).

(Edit: Add: I am running Linux, with python 3.8 and 3.11)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to at least alleviate that problem by reading only Content-Length bytes of the reply.

In the example above this would be

```
self.rfile.read(int(self.headers["Content-Length"]))
```

or in the full cgi situation by resorting to the byte level:

```
byte_len = int(os.getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH"))
sys.stdin.buffer.read(byte_len).decode("utf-8")
```

This is still kind of problematic as one might have to deal web clients lying about the size of of content (i.e. DOS attacks).